# How to include IP of Docker host in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: windows, docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I want to include support for Xdebug in a PHP Docker container, however as part of this, I need to specify the IP of the Windows machine running the Docker container via `XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=${HOST_IP}` - Currently `HOST_IP` is manually specified in a `.env` file, but I'd like to automate this to reduce the setup steps for other users.

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to easily determine the IP of the host machine. It also needs to work on both Windows and Linux Docker hosts, as not all users use Windows as their desktop environment. I also can't use `${HOSTNAME}`, as this fails to resolve in DNS.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

EDIT2: Updating this answer for the newer versions of Docker: From 18.03 onward, Docker For Windows and other Docker platforms have been updated to include a cross-platform hostname for their Docker host, `host.docker.internal` - which is bloody helpful.

Comment: Can you setup xdebug differently? https://xdebug.org/docs/remote has a section labeled "With an unknown IP/multiple developers"

Comment: Yep, I've tried using remote_connect_back and specifying the remote_port for Xdebug. but with no joy.

Answer (score 2):

You might try a formatted `docker info`:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/info/#format-the-output

```
docker info --format '{{json .}}'
docker info --format '{{json .path.to.ip}}'
```

E.g. in a (single-host) `Docker Swarm` you can get the host ip by:

```
docker info --format '{{json .Swarm.NodeAddr}}'
```

Via command substition stored in a variable:

```
docker_host_ip=$(docker info --format '{{json .Swarm.NodeAddr}}')
```

I could not try it on on Windows or on Docker without Swarm ... but `docker info` should work across platforms.

**Update (according to comments below):**
Not really (syntactically) "beautiful" you can use `--format {{index path arrayIndex "Key"}}` with `docker network inspect` and access the first element of an array (index `0`) and then access the map inside this array via its key (`"Gateway"`):

```
docker network inspect docker_dockernet --format '{{index .IPAM.Config 0 "Gateway"}}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not running Swarm, and there's no network information in the JSON output from `docker info --format '{{json .}}`

I can get some interesting information from `docker network inspect` though:

`docker network inspect docker_dockernet --format '{{json .IPAM.Config}}'`
returns
`[{"Subnet":"192.168.1.0/24","Gateway":"192.168.1.1"}]`

Weirdly I can't access the Gateway property though, it returns `Template parsing error: template: :1:12: executing "" at <.IPAM.Config.Gateway>: can't evaluate field Gateway in type interface {}`

Am I missing something there?

Comment: Also, goddamnit StackOverflow, why can't I use newline characters in comments?

Comment: It is an array with a map inside ... I updated the answer and changed from `--format {{json ...` to  `-format {{index ...` for `docker network inspect`

Comment: Output from your suggestion:

`PS C:\mydockerdir> docker network inspect dockerwindows_default --format '{{index .IPAM.Config 0 "Gateway"}}'` returns 
`Template parsing error: template: :1: function "Gateway" not defined`

Comment: And what does `docker network inspect dockerwindows_default --format '{{index .IPAM.Config}}'` output? Does it look the same as with your other network `docker_dockernet`?

Comment: `[{172.18.0.0/16  172.18.0.1 map[]}]` - The docker_dockernet was one I was using at home, but I remember them having the same format in JSON output, at least.

Comment: By the by, awarded you the bounty for this, since you've gotten me closer to a correct answer than I was before!

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for the late response ... I was no longer sure if it is really "the" unviversal/cross-plattform way to get your IP as `--format` seems to differ and I could not reproduce it here. See next comment.

Comment: For me even if `sudo docker network inspect bridge --format '{{index .IPAM.Config}}'` outputs `[{172.17.0.0/16  172.17.0.1 map[]}]` (so similar to your output with omitted "Gateway" - which nevertheless is shown as key with `--format '{{json ...)`, I can still access "Gateway" with `--format '{{index ...` by `sudo docker network inspect bridge --format '{{index .IPAM.Config 0 "Gateway"}}'` and it correctly outputs `172.17.0.1`. Maybe the more reliable way would be to parse the `json` output - either by `regex` or a dedicated tool like `jq`.